# add new data to a buffer while keeping existing data in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, buffer

I want to add new data to my buffer.

I can't use `glBufferSubData` since the buffer does not have enough allocated memory.

When I try to change the buffer size with `glBufferData` beforehand, the already existing data gets lost.

What's the correct way to add new data while keeping existing data?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You should allocate as much memory for a buffer object as you think you will reasonably need, then use however much of that storage that you *current* need to use. Thus, "adding data" is just using more of the existing storage.

Comment: Is it possible though?

Comment: @IceRise: Define "possible." I mean, there's the obvious method of copying the data to another buffer, expanding the original buffer's size, then copying it back, but that's obviously silly, as it requires a bunch of extra memory allocations and memory copying, when you could have just allocated the *correct* amount of storage the first time. Also, it means reallocating a buffer's storage which is again not a good idea.

Comment: Well in my case it's not possible to predict the amount of data in the buffer so it's inevitable that I might need to change to buffer size at some point. Since there is not a efficient method to do this I might just set a fixed limit for each buffer and create more buffers if needed.